# Using Replace and Capitalize function on same array - liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have data set which holds, for instance, this syntax format: brand_shoetype_color (nike_270_red). I want to know how to (1) replace the underscore (_) with a gap (" ") and (2) capitalize each word in the new array.

Desire answers: Nike 270 Red.

Comment: `{{ "nike_270_red" | replace: "_", " " }}`  `{{ 'nike 270 red' | capitalize }}` I'm not sure about that but i thing it will help you

Comment: @Abhishek In your example, the first word only will be capitalized

Comment: Would you be able to use the CSS text-transform property to capitalize the first letter of each word, or does it need to be capitalized in the source HTML as well? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{%- assign your_str = "nike_270_red" -%}
{%- assign words = your_str | split: "_" -%}
{%- capture new_str -%}
  {%- for word in words %}{{ word | capitalize }} {% endfor -%}
{%- endcapture -%}
{{ new_str }}
```

Comment: This is a proper solution, don't know why you received -1 for this. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner just for fun:

`{{ 'nike_270_red' | replace: '_', '_zzzz_' | camelcase | replace: 'Zzzz', ' '  }}`

Where this `_zzzz_` is just a placeholder that I remove afterwards with `Zzzz`.

For reference I will probably not use it in a project but hey the more options the better.

Comment: Nice solution, like it)

Comment: cool man. this solution I've asked will be on production env so I'll prefer something more robust. thanks a lot!